# Delete text block with matching search word

Tags: awk, sed

I am about to write a bash script which should delete a text block (in a textile), where the search word was found. Unfortunately i can not get it to work.

I have a list-file which looks like that

```
[valid_account]
user        = doe.john
passw       = 4567
mac         = 11-22-33-44-bb-cc
s2          = qwe

[valid_account]
user        = kent.clark
passw       = 1234
mac         = 00-11-22-33-aa-bb
s1          = abc
s2          = efg

[valid_account]
user        = bond.james
passw       = 6789
mac         = 44-55-66-77-ee-ff
s4          = bnm

[valid_account]
user        = parker.peter
passw       = 9876
mac         = 77-bb-cc-66-00-aa
s1          = abc
```

if the search word is 00-11-22-33-aa-bb, how can i delete the text block with the search word that the result is this?

```
[valid_account]
user        = doe.john
passw       = 4567
mac         = 11-22-33-44-bb-cc
s2          = qwe

[valid_account]
user        = bond.james
passw       = 6789
mac         = 44-55-66-77-ee-ff
s4          = bnm

[valid_account]
user        = parker.peter
passw       = 9876
mac         = 77-bb-cc-66-00-aa
s1          = abc
```

Comment: Where does this file is coming from ? Seems like a config of an application. Which one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gnu sed

```
sed '/valid_account/!d;:A;N;$bB;/\n$/!bA;:B;/00-11-22-33-aa-bb/d' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v delete_regex='00-11-22-33-aa-bb' -v RS=$'\n\n' -v ORS=$'\n\n' \
    '$0 !~ delete_regex' inputfile
```

Could be changed so that the search string is not interpreted as regex.

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), compact/concise way :

```
$ perl -00ne 'print if !/00-11-22-33-aa-bb/' file
```

or using a variable `str` :

```
str='00-11-22-33-aa-bb' perl -00lne 'print if !/$ENV{"str"}/' file
```

### Output :

```
[valid_account]
user        = doe.john
passw       = 4567
mac         = 11-22-33-44-bb-cc
s2          = qwe

[valid_account]
user        = bond.james
passw       = 6789
mac         = 44-55-66-77-ee-ff
s4          = bnm

[valid_account]
user        = parker.peter
passw       = 9876
mac         = 77-bb-cc-66-00-aa
s1          = abc
```